# Access PHP protected object property (haproxy)

Tags: php, object, properties, private, haproxy

I'm using a modified version of this library (https://github.com/kamermans/HAProxyAPI) to connect to all my loadbalancer instances. 
However, to know whether servers connected are active instances or backup instances I need to adress 'bck' property from the statistics. (I cannot access it using: $loadbalancer['haproxy_stats']->info->line->data->bck)

Note that this property: $loadbalancer['haproxy_stats']->health->backup. is not the one I need, this only indicates whether backup servers are present in this loadbalancer.

How do I access this property?

Example Haproxy Stats from: HAProxy_Stats::get($exec)->getServiceStats($interface,$server);

The result (print_r) looks like this:

HAProxy_Stats_Service Object
(
    [info] => HAProxy_Stats_Info Object
        (
            [map:protected] => Array
                (
                    [pxname] => proxy_name
                    [svname] => service_name
                    [weight] => weight
                    [pid] => process_id
                    [iid] => proxy_id
                    [sid] => service_id
                    [tracked] => tracked
                    [type] => type
                )

```
        [type] =&gt; 2
        [proxy_name] =&gt; core_loadbalancer
        [service_name] =&gt; Core03
        [process_id] =&gt; 1
        [proxy_id] =&gt; 2
        [service_id] =&gt; 3
        [weight] =&gt; 1
        [tracked] =&gt; 
        [line:protected] =&gt; HAProxy_Stats_Line Object
            (
                [data:protected] =&gt; Array
                    (
                        [pxname] =&gt; core_loadbalancer
                        [svname] =&gt; Core03
                        [qcur] =&gt; 0
                        [qmax] =&gt; 0
                        [scur] =&gt; 0
                        [smax] =&gt; 0
                        [slim] =&gt; 20000
                        [stot] =&gt; 0
                        [bin] =&gt; 0
                        [bout] =&gt; 0
                        [dreq] =&gt; 
                        [dresp] =&gt; 0
                        [ereq] =&gt; 
                        [econ] =&gt; 0
                        [eresp] =&gt; 0
                        [wretr] =&gt; 0
                        [wredis] =&gt; 0
                        [status] =&gt; UP
                        [weight] =&gt; 1
                        [act] =&gt; 0
                        [bck] =&gt; 1
                        [chkfail] =&gt; 6
                        [chkdown] =&gt; 0
                        [lastchg] =&gt; 523133
                        [downtime] =&gt; 0
                        [qlimit] =&gt; 
                        [pid] =&gt; 1
                        [iid] =&gt; 2
                        [sid] =&gt; 3
                        [throttle] =&gt; 
                        [lbtot] =&gt; 0
                        [tracked] =&gt; 
                        [type] =&gt; 2
                        [rate] =&gt; 0
                        [rate_lim] =&gt; 
                        [rate_max] =&gt; 0
                        [check_status] =&gt; L4OK
                        [check_code] =&gt; 
                        [check_duration] =&gt; 0
                        [hrsp_1xx] =&gt; 0
                        [hrsp_2xx] =&gt; 0
                        [hrsp_3xx] =&gt; 0
                        [hrsp_4xx] =&gt; 0
                        [hrsp_5xx] =&gt; 0
                        [hrsp_other] =&gt; 0
                        [hanafail] =&gt; 0
                        [req_rate] =&gt; 
                        [req_rate_max] =&gt; 
                        [req_tot] =&gt; 
                        [cli_abrt] =&gt; 0
                        [srv_abrt] =&gt; 0
                        [] =&gt; 
                    )

            )

    )
```

The object continues but there is a character limit...

Answer (score 0):

This would have been answered much sooner if an [issue was created for it](https://github.com/kamermans/HAProxyAPI/issues), but better late than never I guess :)

This is indeed the right property:

```
$loadbalancer['haproxy_stats']->health->backup
```

But, if you are checking the stats of the loadbalancer BACKEND, it will just return the number of backup nodes.  If you want to know if individual nodes are active or backup, you will need to iterate over them like this:

```
foreach ($stats->getBackendNames() as $backend) {
    foreach ($stats->getServerNames($backend) as $server) {
        $service = $stats->getServiceStats($backend, $server);
        echo "$backend:$server\n";
        echo "  Active: {$service->health->active}\n";
        echo "  Backup: {$service->health->backup}\n";
        echo "  Health: {$service->health->status}\n\n";
    }
}
```

This will produce output like this:

```
foo-cloud:FRONTEND
  Active: 
  Backup: 
  Health: OPEN

production-nodes:hiphop-node01-us.foocloud.com
  Active: 1
  Backup: 0
  Health: UP

production-nodes:apache-node01-us.foocloud.com
  Active: 0
  Backup: 1
  Health: UP

production-nodes:hiphop-node02-us.foocloud.com
  Active: 1
  Backup: 0
  Health: UP

production-nodes:apache-node02-us.foocloud.com
  Active: 0
  Backup: 1
  Health: MAINT

production-nodes:BACKEND
  Active: 2
  Backup: 2
  Health: UP

stats:FRONTEND
  Active: 
  Backup: 
  Health: OPEN

stats:BACKEND
  Active: 0
  Backup: 0
  Health: UP
```